# how to reorder columns in jqgrid by dragging column headers

Tags: jqgrid

jqgrid doc in [here](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3ajquery_ui_methods&s%5B%5D=chooser) contains:

method **allow to reorder the grid columns using the mouse**. The only necessary setting in this case is to set the sortable option in jqGrid to true.

I have sortable: true but columns cannot reordered by dragging headers by mouse.  How to re-order columns by dragging columns headers or other way without using column chooser ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To implement sortable columns is really easy. You should just follow [the documentation](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3ajquery_ui_methods#sortable_columns). You should just

1. include `jquery-ui.min.js` additionally to `jquery-ui.css` which are always required. The most people have the file already included because of usage jQuery UI Widgets like Datepicker, Autocomplete, Tabs and so on.
2. add `sortable: true` option to the grid.

Now you can already (see [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/SortableColumns.htm)) drag the column header and drop it on another position.