# Reordering columns, Virtual scroll, gridResize in jqgrid does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jqgrid

I am using jqgrid with Symfony to show a datagrid.

Oleg's answer solved major problems.

Here's my code:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="{{ asset('bundles/productorderlookup/css/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css') }}" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="{{ asset('bundles/productorderlookup/css/ui.jqgrid.css') }}" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="{{ asset('bundles/productorderlookup/css/ui.multiselect.css') }}" />
<style type="text/css">
    span.cellWithoutBackground
    {
        display:block;
        background-image:none;
        margin-right:-2px;
        margin-left:-2px;
        height:14px;
        padding:4px;
    }
</style>
<script src="{{ asset('bundles/productorderlookup/js/i18n/grid.locale-en.js') }}" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('bundles/productorderlookup/js/jquery.jqGrid.src.js') }}" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://jquery-ui.googlecode.com/svn/tags/latest/ui/minified/i18n/jquery-ui-i18n.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-migrate/1.2.1/jquery-migrate.js"></script>
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        jQuery("#list").jqGrid({
            url:"{{ asset('/app_dev.php/_thrace-datagrid/data/user_management') }}",
            datatype: 'json',
            mtype: 'POST',
            colNames:['Product ID','Product Name', 'Product Details'],
            colModel :[
                {name:'id', index:'u.id', width:200,
                    formatter: function (cellvalue) {
                        var color;
                        var val = Number(cellvalue);
                        if (val%3 == 0) {
                            color = 'red';
                        } else if (val%3 == 1) {
                            color = 'yellow';
                        } else if (val%3 == 2){
                            color = 'green';
                        }

                        return '<span class="cellWithoutBackground" style="background-color:' + color + ';">' + cellvalue + '</span>';
                    }},
                {name:'productName', index:'u.productName', width:200, editable: true},
                {name:'productDetails', index:'u.productDetails', width:200, align:'right', editable: true}
            ],
            autowidth: true,
            //width: 800,
            height: 600,
            gridview: true,
            autoencode: true,
            shrinkToFit: false,
            pager: '#pager',
            rowNum:50,
            rowTotal: 1000000,
            rowList:[50, 100, 500, 1000],
            rownumWidth: 40,
            viewrecords: true,
            caption: 'Product Order Lookup',
            sortname: 'u.id',
            sortorder: 'asc',
            sortable:true,
            //multiselect: true,
            ondblClickRow: function(rowid) {
                jQuery(this).jqGrid('editGridRow', rowid);
            },
            footerrow: true,
            gridComplete: function() {
                var $grid = $('#list');
                var colSum = $grid.jqGrid('getCol', 'id', false, 'sum');
                $grid.jqGrid('footerData', 'set', { 'id': colSum });
                },
            loadonce:false,
            editurl:"{{ asset('/app_dev.php/_thrace-datagrid/row-action/user_management') }}",
            subGrid: true,
            subGridRowExpanded: function(subgrid_id, row_id) {
                var subgrid_table_id;
                var pager_id = "p_"+subgrid_table_id;
                subgrid_table_id = subgrid_id+"_t";
                jQuery("#"+subgrid_id).html("<table id='"+subgrid_table_id+"' class='scroll'></table><div id='"+pager_id+"' class='scroll'></div>");
                jQuery("#"+subgrid_table_id).jqGrid({
                    url:"{{ asset('/app_dev.php/_thrace-datagrid/data/product_order_management') }}",
                    postData: {
                        masterGridRowId: row_id
                    },
                    datatype: "json",
                    mtype: 'POST',
                    colNames: ['oid','orderno'],
                    colModel: [
                        {name:"oid",index:"o.id",key:true},
                        {name:"orderno",index:"o.orderno", editable: true}
                    ],
                    height: '100%',
                    pager: pager_id,
                    rowNum:50,
                    //editData: {pid: row_id}, // edit options
                    editurl:"{{ asset('/app_dev.php/_thrace-datagrid/row-action/product_order_management') }}",
                    rowList:[50, 100, 500, 1000]
                });
                jQuery("#"+subgrid_table_id).jqGrid('navGrid',"#"+pager_id,{
                        idPrefix: "s_" + row_id + "_",
                        del:true,
                        add:true,
                        edit:true,
                        addtext: 'Add',
                        edittext: 'Edit',
                        deltext: 'Delete',
                        searchtext: 'Search',
                        refreshtext: 'Reload'},
                        {editData: {pid: row_id}},
                        {editData: {pid: row_id}},
                        {editData: {pid: row_id}},
                        {multipleSearch:true}
                );
                jQuery("#"+subgrid_table_id).jqGrid('filterToolbar',{stringResult: true,searchOnEnter : true});
            }

        });
        jQuery("#list").jqGrid('navGrid','#pager',{del:true,add:true,edit:true},{},{},{},{multipleSearch:true}).navButtonAdd('#pager',{
            caption: "Excel",
            buttonicon:"ui-icon-disk",
            onClickButton: function(){
                exportExcel($(this));
            },
            position:"last"
        });
        jQuery("#list").jqGrid('filterToolbar',{ defaultSearch: 'cn', stringResult: true,searchOnEnter : true});
        jQuery('#list').jqGrid('gridResize');
    });
```

I followed the instructions as Oleg suggested like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8930663/how-to-reorder-columns-in-jqgrid-by-dragging-column-headers) and it still gives me the same problem.

Couple of things I am facing problems with. 
(1) [SOLVED] My virtual scroll is not working. I played around with height, width and shrinkToFit too. But it still does not seem to work. The only thing happening when setting scroll:true is that the paging gets disabled.

(2) [SOLVED] Sortable:true does not work. I have included the necessary css and js files and sortable still does not work.

(3) [SOLVED] Also gridResize is not working. I do get the different cursor for changing the size but upon trying to change the size, it does not seem to work.

Only thing wrong I can think of is including too many css and js files.

Any help would be appreciated on this. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code which you posted have many problems.

First of all you inserted `jquery-1.11.3.js`, then `jqueryui/1.8.13/jquery-ui.min.js` and then `jqueryui/1.7.2/jquery-ui.js`. Including of multiple versions of JavaScript libraries on one page can break functionality of the included library. You hove to remove the old jQuery UI 1.7.2.

I should include multiple `document.ready` handlers on the page only if you do *absolutely independent things inside of the handlers*. What you do are *dependent* calls. You can use `navGrid`, `filterToolbar` and other jqGrid methods **only after the grid is created**. So you should include the content of all handlers in one, first, `document.ready` handler.

The call of `columnChooser` in the form have no sense. You should include the button in navigator toolbar and call the method `columnChooser` only incide of  onClick handler of the button.

You should include `idPrefix` option in subgrids which you create inside of `subGridRowExpanded`. Every subgrid should have **unique** prefix. The problem is: multiple subgrids can be opened at the same time and the ids of the rows could be the same. To protect the code to produce id duplicates you should use `idPrefix` option. For example `idPrefix: "s_" + row_id + "_"`.

The last remark: I don't recommend to use `scroll: true` at all because of many restriction which exist in the usage of another features of jqGrid and different other implementation problems.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. Not just this time but every time I search something on Stack Overflow related to jquery/jqGrid your answers are always precise and solves the problem. You truly are great.
I did exactly what you said and solved 2 of my 3 problems. However Virtual scroll is still not working. I will update the code so you have a better look.

Comment: I just removed scroll:true. Should solve my problem for now. Thank you so much once again.